# Recursively copying files from a source to a single directory including searching ZIP files

Tags: powershell, copy, zip, copy-item

I'd like to use Powershell to recursively copy a specific set of files from a series of sub directories into a single folder (without the source folder structure). The files all follow the filename format "Writing (*).xlsm". Also, some of the directories have their files stored in a ZIP file and I'd like to search these ZIP files for this same file name.

I've seen plenty of solutions that can copy the files but the result recreates the folder structure that the files were found in but I need to capture them all into a single directory, and I have not seen anything that seems to include the ability to add the opening of ZIP files to the search.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I have, yes. I'm not skilled enough to start from scratch, and I don't use PS enough to know many of the finer points but I can take code and modify it to my needs most times. In this case however, I have not been able to find anything that works to copy the files without also creating their subfolders and I have not seen anything that I can use to include extracting and copying these files from zipped archives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Path = "C:\"
$Destination = "C:\Destination"
$Files = @()
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path" -Filter "Writing*.xml" -Recurse).Fullname

#Zip
$ZipFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path" -Filter "*.Zip" -Recurse).Fullname
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$ToRemove = @()
Foreach($Zip in $ZipFiles){
        $RawFiles = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Zip).Entries
        foreach($RawFile in $RawFiles) {
            If($RawFile.FullName -like "Writing*.xml"){
                $outpath = $Zip.Remove($Zip.Length - 4)
                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($Zip, $outpath)
                $Files += "$outpath\" + $RawFiles.Fullname
                $ToRemove += $outpath
            }
        }

    }

Foreach($File in $Files){
    Copy-Item -Path $Files -Destination $Destination
}

Foreach($Folder in $ToRemove){
    Remove-Item -Path $Folder -Force
}
```

Comment: This worked great for files not in zip files. On the zip files, nothing appears to happen, it just moves onto the next file. I also noticed that some of my compressed files are rar format and when changing the filter from zip to rar it throws an error for every file it encounters.

Comment: After looking more closely, I needed to modify the file name searched for in the zip files. When used against these files however, it threw an error. Watching the progress, it unzipped the archive, then prompted with a message box "The item at... has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified..all children will be removed." Continuing removed all the extracted files and did not leave the target file behind.

Comment: I also noticed that some of the archives are in rar format but changing the *.zip to *.rar only threw an additional error "End of Central Directory record could not be found." Is there an opportunity to add anything to account for either zip or rar?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265827/extract-files-to-same-folder-as-archive-using-recursive-to-search-all-directorie). This is a solution shows how you can extract zip and rar. For this you need the additional tool 7zip